# Как на определенном медиа-запросе CSS включать нужный кусок JS кода?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries, match-media

Всем здравия! Как мне, например, на `@media(max-width: 992px)` задействовать определенный кусок JS кода?

То есть до `992px` у меня работает один код, а после `992px` уже другой.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Необходимо работать с шириной окна именно на стороне JS.

```
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 992){
   doSomething()
}else{
   doSomething2()
}
```

И еще, это хорошо бы вставить и при загрузке и при resize, что бы все не сломалось при повороте экрана смартфона,например.

[Вот тут описание методов на https://learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window)

Comment: Да, я знаю что на стороне JS, просто не знал, как это правильно назвать) Спасибо!

Answer (score 12):

Для этого можно воспользоваться методом интерфейса [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), под названием [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 992px)").matches) {
  // работает один код
} else {
  // работает уже другой 
}
```

Comment: Да откуда вы это все знаете???? Я о таких методах впервые слышу