# Как сделать чтобы скрипт работал только при определенной ширине окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, match-media

Всем привет!

Нашел статью о том как сделать меню аккордеон, вот собственно [сама статья](https://keengo.ru/blog/javascript/vertikalnoe-menyu-akkordeon-na-jquery/).

Мне нужно чтобы МЕНЮ работало как аккордеон при ширине окна меньше `540px`.

Пробовал через событие RESIZE, возникали проблемы связанные с тем что, если у пользователя ширина окна изначально меньше `540px`, то скрипт не сработает.

Как мне сделать, чтобы при окне меньше `540px`, скрипт работал, а если больше `540px` - нет?

Всем спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172089/ - отвечает на вопрос?) В функции, которая срабатывает при клике на аккордион, вначале добавить `if (window.innerWidth < 540) return;`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161950

Answer (score 3):

Для этого можно воспользоваться методом интерфейса [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), под названием [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 540px)").matches) {
  // ... ваша логика
  // которая не станет выполняться
  // если размер больше 540px
}
```